# Directory to file with Luks key password

Tags: password, luks, passwd

I wondering where are places luks key password. For example password for root is in `etc/shadow`. Where I can find file with luks key password?

I add this 
`cryptsetup luksAddKey --key-slot 1 /dev/sda5` what is directory of file with this password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key material is stored after the LUKS partition header (so no file).

The key slots can be viewed using:

```
cryptsetup luksDump /dev/<your_disk>
```

See:

- https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/wikis/LUKS-standard/on-disk-format.pdf

Comment: Yes, i know about the header. So is some way  to automaticly add cryptsetup key via script? Let's say i have a 10 Pc and I wanne add the same key to all of it. How to do this? Do you know?

Comment: @SanHolo I believe, that would be the same as in your original question `cryptsetup luksAddKey ...` or possibly `cryptsetup luksChangeKey ...`. You can also add `--key-file` option which could be scriptable  (Did not test is though). Please see `man cryptsetup`.